# Understand wrong data shown on the e-commerce. Cloudflare - FrontDoor and Multiple Azure AppService instance

Tags: azure, cloudflare

I've recently migrated a VM that was hosting an Asp.NET MVC application + Wordpress blog on a separate AppService for MVC + another one for Wordpress.

We have now this configuration:

1. Cloudflare for caching page content + some redirect
2. An Azure Frontdoor that redirects traffic to the Azure appservices
3. We have 10 instances of the AppService.
4. Each service has its own internal cache.

Now we are experiencing some portion of the page that shows items in the wishlist or item in the cart that seems to be cached until we purge Cloudflare cache.

If we don't have CloudFlare in the middle, I expect that Azure FrontDoor is acting as a load balancer between the instances and it uses the sticky session to be sure that the user only sees his data.

If we have Cloudflare in the middle... how are those sticky sessions managed? My suspect is that from Cloudflare to FrontDoor it's mixing things up.

This is a schema

[image]

I need to be sure that from CF to FD the sticky session are kept.